# Cant add exchange user with Office 2007 in Windows 10 on Parallels on an Apple,

Tags: windows-10, exchange, microsoft-office-2007, parallels

Hi I am a newbie here so lets see how you guys can help please?

I have a client with an Apple computer, he is running Parallels in which he has Windows 10 running Office 2007 Enterprise. When using Outlook 2007 I tried adding a user. The first screen comes up with the name, email, and password blocks but no "NEXT" button, never mind I pressed  and it went in.

It contacted the server but I couldn't save the profile in Outlook. No problem so I exited Outlook and added the profile using mail 32bit in control panel. I couldn't save it as Outlook was not running. But if its running it cant save it either. Is this an Apple/Parallels problem or an Office2007/Windows 10 problem?

Any ideas?

Comment: Why have parallels and windows10 - office is available directly on mac...

Comment: They have what they have. He was given a licence for his old work and he chose to run it on the Mac in Parallels. Its also available free online as opposed to 365 but that what he has. Thanks for the thought though.